# xubuntu 13.10: automount usb sticks

Tags: usb, xubuntu, automount

I have a freshly installed Xubuntu 13.10 on the Lenovo T520 laptop. In the 
 *Settings Manager — Removable Drives and Media* I have the *Mount removable drives when hot-plugged* and *Mount removable media when inserted* checked.

But when I insert an usb-stick (VFAT) it doesn't get auto-mounted. So I can't access it from terminal. It gets mounted only when I click on the drive icon on the desktop or in Thunar.

Can I fix it somehow?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved?

Comment: Well, I use Ubuntu instead of Xubuntu now and there is no such problem :)

Comment: +1 xubuntu doesn't seem to have the gnome automounting stuff. It's running `xfce` :( any other solution for automounting usb sticks?